# Convert bit string array to byte array

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have the following binary string (actually a bit array)
"1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0"

which I want to convert to a byte array.
I need this for an embedded report code functions which only accepts a byte array. I've converted this function from powershell.

I found this but it's C#

```
string source = "1,1,1,0,0";

 byte[] result = source
   .Split(',')
   .Select(item => byte.Parse(item))
   .ToArray();
```

This does not work in report builder ('Select' is not a member of 'System.Array'.)

```vb
Dim source As String = "1,1,1,0,0"
Dim result As Byte() = source.Split(","c).[Select](Function(item) Byte.Parse(item)).ToArray()
```

If I add System.Linq as suggested I'm still getting an error:
'Select' is not a member of 'Linq'.

```vb
Dim source As String() = "1,1,1,0,0".Split(","c)
Dim result As Byte() = System.Linq.Select(Function(source) Byte.Parse(source)).ToArray()
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is nothing but a thinly veiled request for code conversion.  There are plenty of online tools to perform this service.

Comment: @TnTinMn, I don't see any veil.

Comment: You can use [online converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert VB to C# or C# to VB.

Comment: Thanks @TnTinMn you have been very helpful. 
If you bothered to read the text you would have seen that I've converted the whole function from powershell without anyone's help with zero vb knowledge. So I don't see any veil here. I just wanted some help because reporting services does not understand anything that is not string.

Comment: @Han I'm sorry that I've not specified this but I used a converter. Unfortunately the code is not converted properly.

Comment: Does Report Builder allow you to reference System.Linq?  That's where the `Select` method is defined.  The only other obvious thing I see wrong with your VB code is that your call to split should have `","c` and it should work.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes! I can add the add the reference (System.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a) but then I need to call it with the full name (System.Linq). I tried various combinations, can you please show me how to add this to the current example?

Comment: The converter won't perfectly convert your code. But you can use the converted code as guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the function more closely I realized that the input can be any array so I modified the type of the array to string and updated my input accordingly. Tank you guys for trying to help.

Function

```vb
Function GetSQLProductKey(ByVal astrBinaryKey As String(), ByVal intVersion As Integer) As String
    Dim achrKeyChars As Char() = {"B", "C", "D", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "M", "P", "Q", "R", "T", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "2", "3", "4", "6", "7", "8", "9"}
    Dim strSQLProductKey As String
    Dim iastrBinaryKey As Long
    Dim iachrKeyChars As Long
    Dim iastrBinaryKeyOuterLoop As Long
    Dim iastrBinaryKeyInnerLoop As Long
    Try
        If (intVersion >= 11) Then
            iastrBinaryKey = 0
        Else
            iastrBinaryKey = 52
        End If
        For iastrBinaryKeyOuterLoop = 24 To 0 Step -1
            iachrKeyChars = 0
            For iastrBinaryKeyInnerLoop = 14 To 0 Step -1
                iachrKeyChars = iachrKeyChars * 256 Xor astrBinaryKey(iastrBinaryKeyInnerLoop + iastrBinaryKey)
                astrBinaryKey(iastrBinaryKeyInnerLoop + iastrBinaryKey) = Math.Truncate(iachrKeyChars / 24)
                iachrKeyChars = iachrKeyChars Mod 24
            Next iastrBinaryKeyInnerLoop
            strSQLProductKey = achrKeyChars(iachrKeyChars) + strSQLProductKey
            If (iastrBinaryKeyOuterLoop Mod 5) = 0 And iastrBinaryKeyOuterLoop <> 0 Then
                strSQLProductKey = "-" + strSQLProductKey
            End If
        Next iastrBinaryKeyOuterLoop
    Catch
        strSQLProductKey = "Cannot decode product key."
    End Try
    GetSQLProductKey = strSQLProductKey
End Function
```

Function Call SSRS

```vb
Code.GetSQLProductKey(Split(Replace(Fields!ProductKey.Value, " ",""), ","), Left(Fields!Version.Value, 2))
```